# Swift 2.2 indexOf for struct part in array

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing, struct

I simply would like to find the index of an array of structs containing a search item in the struct. similar to this:

```
struct Address{
    var name:String
    var town:String
}

var allAddresses = [Address]()
let newAddress = Address.init(name: "Paul", town: "Heidelberg")
allAddresses.append(newAddress)


//...
let found = allAddresses.name.indexOf("Paul")
//...
```

but i get

> error: value of type '[Address]' has no member 'name'

Is this somehow possible in this manner?
Iterating through the array would pose other problems for me!

Comment: Great! I learned something new. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to call `indexOf` on the array and use the closure syntax for the predicate:

```
let found = allAddresses.indexOf { $0.name == "Paul" }
```